# How to grant permission for something in Japanese

Tags: grammar, subsidiary-verbs, causation, modality, permission

I know that させてくれないか is *won't you let me?*
But how do I say *allow*? させてあげる *I'll let You!*.
I want it to be "something + the auxiliary *ageru*".

Btw.
Why is 借りしてもいい right but not 借りてもいい ?!?!?

I want it like this:

> (部下に) よし。そいつを殺させてあげる。はははは (悪声)

I want to grant permission without a request having been made in the first place, and I want to be firm when I grant the permission.

Comment: 借りてもいい? is natural and 借りしてもいい? is unnatural but お借りしてもいい? is a polite way of saying of 借りてもいい?.

Answer (score 3):

～させてあげる is perfectly correct, but in your context (i.e., to sound firm, bossy...) I think you could use やる instead of あげる, as in:

> よし。そいつを殺**させてやる**。はははは

---

And, as stated in the comment by @Yuuichi, 借り**し**てもいい is not correct. You'd say 借りてもいい, or **お**借り**し**てもいい in 謙譲語/humble language. （Examples of the humble 「お + 連用形 (continuative form) + する」 form: 借りる ⇒ お借りする, 届ける ⇒ お届けする, うかがう ⇒ おうかがいする）

Comment: Alternatively, you could also say「殺させてやろう。」「殺させてやるぞ。」「殺してもいいぞ。」 etc...